# If Cell to immediate Left colored, then copy contents into this cell

Tags: vba, excel, colors

This is what the theoretical Excel syntax would look like if it were possible to execute this without VBA:

IF(**Cell to immediate left = colored (or filled)**, **copy & paste contents into this cell**, **copy & paste contents of cell above into this cell**).

How would I do this in VBA?

Comment: what do you have in the first cell above the current cell into which you want to copy values?

Comment: You'll get a much better response if you show some effort (ie, your own code). To start, google "VBA How to check cell color", then "VBA Copy and paste cell contents". If that's too advanced, start with "VBA how to set up a loop" and "VBA IF statement". Get some of that working, then come back and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write the surrounding code to loop through the cells you want to evaluate, but the crux of it would be something like this:

```
If Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex > xlNone Then
    Range("B2") = Range("A2").Value
Else
    Range("B1") = Range("A2").Value
End If
```

The loop could be a For loop, maybe something like:

```
For i = 2 to <whatever>
    If Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex > xlNone Then
        Range("B" & i) = Range("A" & i).Value
    Else
        Range("B" & i - 1) = Range("A" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF in the VBA:

```
Function Color(MyCell As Range)
If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 Then
    Result = 1
Else
    Result = 0
End If
Color = Result
End Function
```

and then use the following formula in **B2** to fill down the cells:

```
=IF(color(A2)=1,A2,B1)
```

hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As a UDF inputting the Cell to evaluate fill:

```
Function CellColored(rng As Range) As Variant

    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex > xlNone Then
        CellColored = rng.Value2
    Else
        CellColored = Empty
    End If

End Function
```

As UDF without input, just assuming criteria cell is to the right of calling cell:

```
Function CellColored() As Variant

    If Application.Caller.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex > xlNone Then
        CellColored = Application.Caller.Offset(0, 1).Value2
    Else
        CellColored = Empty
    End If

End Function
```

You would then call the function as `CellColored(A2)` or `CellColored()` in the second version. Cheers,